# How do you click an expander button in Python with Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am working on a script for selenium to open a webpage, and click a series of buttons. The first button is an Expander button, shown in the below image

[image: Expand Button]

The HTML code from inspecting the button is below, but the button itself is "class="dojoxExpandoIcon dojoxExpandoIconLeft qa-button-toc"

```
<div class="dojoExpandoPaneInner">
        <div data-dojo-attach-point="titleWrapper" class="dojoxExpandoTitle">
            <div class="dojoxExpandoContainer">
                <div class="dojoxExpandoIcon dojoxExpandoIconLeft qa-button-toc" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onIconNodeClick" tabindex="0" aria-controls="slideout"><span class="a11yNode">X</span></div>
            </div>
```

The xpath as well, is as follows:

```
/html[@class='dj_webkit dj_chrome dj_contentbox has-webkit has-no-quirks svg']/body[@class='claro original']/div[@id='border']/div[@id='slideout']/div[@class='dojoExpandoPaneInner']/div[@class='dojoxExpandoTitle']/div[@class='dojoxExpandoContainer']/div[@class='dojoxExpandoIcon dojoxExpandoIconLeft qa-button-toc']
```

To find this button, I tried the following code one at a time.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class^='dojoxExpandoIcon']")    # find expander by class name
# driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class^='dojoxExpandoIcon dojoxExpandoIconLeft qa-button-toc']")    # find expander by class name
# driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.dojoxExpandoContainer")
```

However, none of them have worked at all, and result in errors such as

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.dojoxExpandoIcon.dojoxExpandoIconLeft.qa-button-toc"}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: is there any iframe ? pls check

Comment: @cruisepandey no iframe. I added the full xpath of the dropdown on the page, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting until the locator is clickable:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dojoxExpandoIcon.dojoxExpandoIconLeft.qa-button-toc")))
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".dojoxExpandoIcon.dojoxExpandoIconLeft.qa-button-toc").click()
```

If the number of classes is not stable, remove the ones that are changing and leave only stable ones, for example:

```
.dojoxExpandoIconLeft.qa-button-toc
```

Here I just removed one of classes.

Read more about waits here https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html.

Comment: Is this approach any different than using time.sleep? I usually give a web page at least 30 seconds to open with time.sleep(30) which basically pauses before taking the next step in the code.

Comment: It's very different. It waits till the element is found and right after it's found, it's clicked. So, it's basically saving your time, cost effective. It page takes 30 seconds to load usually, then change 15 to 30 seconds the the explicit wait.

Comment: No. It didn't work. I got a stack trace exception timeout for it being unable to locate the element. I'm stumped. The HTML code is there.... Is there any way to do it by x_path instead of CSS? I put the full xpath in my code.

Comment: Ok, put the full html better.